# Cannot open PHP file with cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

Right, I have just swapped my hosting company from one that used a rip off of cPanel to one that actually uses cPanel. I realised that I needed to install Sphider search, not a problem, I know how to do that, thing is, I can't open install.php file. There is no button like on my old hosting account. How would I go about opening the file?

Comment: Visit the `install.php` from your browser, not from cPanel.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you, I am having a huge silly moment

Comment: No problem, happens sometimes :).

Answer (score 1):

Visit the `install.php` from your browser, not from cPanel. This is probably the intended way to install your Sphider software.